# text disappears after '&' a space, linear ingredient

Tags: html, css

If I put "NEWS & EVENTS", the 'EVENTS' will disappear.
But if I change '&' to '#', it works fine. How can I use '&' without causing text disappearing

```css
.title {
  width: 1438px;
  height: 142px;
  left: 94px;
  top: 201px;
  font-family: "Eurostile";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 180px;
  line-height: 78.8%;
  /* identical to box height, or 142px */
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: linear-gradient(95.99deg, #CE9B58 25.39%, #FFEC83 73.41%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
  <h1 class="title">NEWS & EVENTS</h1>
  <h1 class="title">NEWS # EVENTS</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: To understand what is going on, remove the clip and transparent settings. You’ll see that the word EVENTS is there after the  ampersand but on the next line as the text overall is too wide for one line. But the linear gradient colors don't extend to that line so the word isn’t seen when the clip is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The & is wider than the #, so you can simply increase the width of your .title:

```css
.title {
  width: 1488px;
  height: 142px;
  left: 94px;
  top: 201px;
  font-family: "Eurostile";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 180px;
  line-height: 78.8%;
  /* identical to box height, or 142px */
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: linear-gradient(95.99deg, #CE9B58 25.39%, #FFEC83 73.41%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
  <h1 class="title">NEWS & EVENTS</h1>
  <h1 class="title">NEWS # EVENTS</h1>
</div>
```

The width, height, top, left and font-style probably aren't necessary:

```css
.title {
  font-family: "Eurostile";
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 11.25rem;
  line-height: 78.8%;
  /* identical to box height, or 142px */
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: linear-gradient(95.99deg, #CE9B58 25.39%, #FFEC83 73.41%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
  <h1 class="title">NEWS & EVENTS</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to *escape* special characters in HTML. Try this instead: `&#38`;

Comment: That's not the issue actually